# applications linked to workspaces

Tags: 12.04, workspaces, application-switcher

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and I found a weird behaviour in the multi-workspace management.

Let's say that I have a couple of terminals opened in one workspace, and that I want to do something else in another workspace. I move to that workspace and then I click on the terminal icon. Immediately I am taken to the initial workspace.

This is similar to the multiple workspace behaviour in Os X and it is entirely undesirable. How can I disable the application-workspace association in 12.04?

Thanks